# Internet Explorer и Class JS

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Столкнулся с проблемой. Имеется js class. В любом нормальном браузере работает как мне надо. но только не в ie(IE 11).

```
class Test {
}
```

Ругается на синтаксическую ошибку в первой же строке (SCRIPT1002: Синтаксическая ошибка)
Подскажите кто знает, как завести скрипт.

Comment: поддержки нет https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: @ThisMan, капец.. Проклятый IE

Comment: можете использовать `babel` https://babeljs.io/

Comment: @ThisMan, спасибо, сейчас посмотрю что за зверь и как его приручить.

Comment: @ThisMan, а вы работали с babel? Если я не использую редактор кода вроде vscode, его можно установить? Думал там будет вроде библиотеки js подключаемой..

Comment: у него нет привязки к редактору, нужен только `npm` + `nodejs`

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Answer (score 0):

```js
function A (B) {this.B = B}
A.prototype.C = function () {
    console.log(this.B)
}
new A('D').C();
```